# Ngx-slider set value to NaN on the page load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an ngx-slider. I want the user to be able to drag from any point on the slider. currently, the starting point is always 0.

I don't want any starting point for the slider

[Here's demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-slider-styled-slider-example-ktyouh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
` value: number = NaN;
 highValue: number = NaN;
 sliderArray = [
 {
  legend: 'a',
  value: 0,
 },
 {
  legend: 'b',
  value: 1,
 },
 {
  legend: 'c',
  value: 2,
 },
 {
  legend: 'd',
  value: 3,
 },
];
get options() {
return {
  showTicks: true,
  stepsArray: this.sliderArray,
  hidePointerLabels: true,
  hideLimitLabels: true,
  // noSwitching: true
 };
}

getEvent(e: ChangeContext) {
 if (Number.isNaN(e.value) && e.highValue > 0) {
  this.value = e.highValue;
 }
}

<ngx-slider
[(value)]="value"
(userChange)="getEvent($event)"
[(highValue)]="highValue"
[options]="options"
></ngx-slider>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can set:

```
highValue: number = 3;
```